# Android ADK accessory popping up a empty empty dialog box

Tags: android, usb, host, adk

I'm making an accessory using Sparkfun's electric sheep board.  Previously, my code worked perfectly fine and I could communicate with the usb accessory. Recently though, instead of popping up the message box to give the accessory permission, it pops up a blank message box that takes up the entire screen with no text or buttons.  I recreated my entire eclipse project yesterday with the exact same code and it was working again perfectly.  However, today I started working on it only to find out that I'm getting the blank message box again.

Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: Found the answer immediately after posting it.  I was using a quick image for the icon and hadn't worried about re-sizing it yet and instead just let the app re-scale it when necessary until I got around to shrinking it. Turns out, the message/dialog boxes do not scale the icon to the application and was trying to render it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer immediately after posting it. I was using a quick image for the icon and hadn't worried about re-sizing it yet and instead just let the app re-scale it when necessary until I got around to shrinking it. Turns out, the message/dialog boxes do not scale the icon to the application and was trying to render it.